# I can't print the api I pulled on the mapmarker

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I pulled the data from the mapmarker, when I print, I see all of them, but I cannot get them from the example ( quake.latitude ). Error. Even if it was a list, I had taken it by typing "(quakes) { quake in" in parentheses, but now I don't know how to do it through mapview.

```
struct MapAnnotationsView: View {

@State var quakes: [EarthQuake] = []

@State private var region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 38.9520281, longitude: 35.6980142), span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 30, longitudeDelta: 10))

let placeArray: [Place] = [Place(title: {quake.latitude}, coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.8008, longitude: 27.2465))]

var body: some View {
    Map(coordinateRegion: $region, annotationItems: placeArray) { annotation in
        // This makes a generic annotation that takes a View
        MapAnnotation(coordinate: annotation.coordinate) {
            // This is your custom view
            AnnotationView(placeName: annotation.title)
        }
    } .onAppear {
        Api().getEarthQuake { (quakes) in
            self.quakes = quakes
            
        }
    }
}
}
```

[Error code screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVTis.png)

Comment: Since you aren't including `EarthQuake`, `Place`, `Api`, or `AnnotationView` in your code, it's unlikely to be able to give a concrete. In the screenshot, the error is because you can't access another property when setting an initial value of a separate property. I think you probably want `placeArray` to be a computed property.

Comment: I understood what you said, but I can't add here as I added in the example below. I am not able to pull the quakes.latitude js api object.

`List(quakes) { quake in
            HStack(){`

Comment: I don't know what that means. Does my suggestion to make `placeArray` a computed property make sense to you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
struct MapAnnotationsView: View {

@State private var region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 38.9520281, longitude: 35.6980142), span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 30, longitudeDelta: 10))

@State private var placeArray: [Place] = []

var body: some View {
    Map(coordinateRegion: $region, annotationItems: placeArray) { annotation in
        // This makes a generic annotation that takes a View
        MapAnnotation(coordinate: annotation.coordinate) {
            // This is your custom view
            AnnotationView(placeName: annotation.title)
        }
    } .onAppear {
        Api().getEarthQuake { (quakes) in
            let tempArray = quakes.map{ quake in
                 Place(title: "\(quake.latitude)", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.8008, longitude: 27.2465))
            }
            self.placeArray = tempArray
        }
    }
}
}
```

As this is not a reproducible example there might be some typos involved here which you would have to address yourself.

---

Explenation:
Your property `placeArray` cannot depend on another property. To get an array of places to provide to your map you need to create these after you loaded the earthquakes from your API and assign them. Using a `@State var` ensures your View gets updated.

Comment: Seems like you may as well get rid of `@State var quakes: [EarthQuake] = []` and just use is at as a local variable in the closure if it's just functioning to create the `Place` array.

Comment: @jnpdx you are right. I´ve changed it to be more accurate.

Comment: I did as you said, but this time I get a region error.

[error screenshot][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BAYkS.png

Comment: I also get some errors when editing.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pd4uq.png

Comment: @TugayÖzayASAN edit again. It is very hard to do this, since you decided to not provide a reproducible example. These are simple errors to fix.

Comment: when the application comes to the white screen, it redirects to the code. It won't open.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Hikw.png

Comment: You've added a breakpoint in Xcode (see the highlighted arrow on line 5?). You should remove that.

Comment: The errors are gone, I can't print the number thing in the api here. This type of error

https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0kbB.png

Comment: @TugayÖzayASAN I think i answered your question. You are changing the code as we speek. I´m not willing to sit here all night and try to solve every change you come up with. You seem to lack basic understanding of Swift.

Comment: I am not changing the code, I just added the directly written latitude and longitude data, but it did not work. Let me know if there is a course you recommend, I just wanted a little more help.

Comment: You don't use `\()` unless you're inside a `String` -- you've tried to add longitude and latitude parameters wrapped with that syntax. Remove the `\()` surrounding each one.

Comment: I did as you said and it worked. it works. @jnpdx